# Listing WorkItem State Reasons programmatically

Tags: tfs

We have a customised TFS workflow, I want to be able to access the Reasons I can close a Bug (change the state from Active to Closed) from TFS so that we don't have to update our code every time we want to tweak our process.

This is what I have so far:

```
  WorkItemType wiType = this.GetWorkItemStore().Projects[this.ProjectName].WorkItemTypes["Bug"];
  var reason = wiType.FieldDefinitions["Reason"];
  var state = wiType.FieldDefinitions["State"];

  var filterList = new FieldFilterList();      
  FieldFilter filter = new FieldFilter(wiType.FieldDefinitions[CoreField.State], "Active");
  filterList.Add(filter);

    var allowedReasons = reason.FilteredAllowedValues(filterList);
```

However I'm not getting any results. I'd like to get a list of all the reasons why I can close a bug (Not Reproduceable, Fixed etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any easy way to get the transition via API directly as I know since the API read the allowed values from database directly.

The alternative way would be export the workitemtype definition via WorkItemType.Export() method and then get the information from it. Vaccano's answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203506/tfs-api-is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-the-transitions-for-a-workitem-type) provided the entire code sample you can use.

Edited to give an example of how I solved this using the above recommendation:

```
public static List<Transition> GetTransistions(this WorkItemType workItemType)
{
  List<Transition> currentTransistions;

  // See if this WorkItemType has already had it's transistions figured out.
  _allTransistions.TryGetValue(workItemType, out currentTransistions);
  if (currentTransistions != null)
    return currentTransistions;

  // Get this worktype type as xml
  XmlDocument workItemTypeXml = workItemType.Export(false);

  // Create a dictionary to allow us to look up the "to" state using a "from" state.
  var newTransistions = new List<Transition>();

  // get the transistions node.
  XmlNodeList transitionsList = workItemTypeXml.GetElementsByTagName("TRANSITIONS");

  // As there is only one transistions item we can just get the first
  XmlNode transitions = transitionsList[0];

  // Iterate all the transitions
  foreach (XmlNode transition in transitions)
  {
    XmlElement defaultReasonNode = transition["REASONS"]["DEFAULTREASON"];
    var defaultReason = defaultReasonNode.Attributes["value"].Value;

    var otherReasons = new List<string>();
    XmlNodeList otherReasonsNodes = transition["REASONS"].SelectNodes("REASON");
    foreach (XmlNode reasonNode in otherReasonsNodes)
    {
      var reason = reasonNode.Attributes["value"].Value;
      otherReasons.Add(reason);
    }

    // save off the transistion 
    newTransistions.Add(new Transition
    {
      From = transition.Attributes["from"].Value,
      To = transition.Attributes["to"].Value,
      DefaultReason = defaultReason,
      OtherReasons = otherReasons
    });

  }

  // Save off this transition so we don't do it again if it is needed.
  _allTransistions.Add(workItemType, newTransistions);

  return newTransistions;
}
```

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution so rather than creating my own I've copied in the adapted code from your linked question - please feel free to edit!